# Retrieving a record's previous column value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Let's say I have this table:

```
|ID|ForeignKey|Number|
| 1|    A     |     5|
| 2|    B     |     3|
| 3|    A     |     2|
| 4|    B     |     5|
```

and I want to get this output:

```
|ForeignKey|PrevNumber|CurNumber|
| A        |         0|        5|
| B        |         0|        3|
| A        |         5|        2|
| B        |         3|        5|
```

So how can I retrieve a record's previous attribute?
I tried using different kinds of join like left, inner but to no avail

Comment: what are try to ask ?

Comment: How do I achieve the output shown on the second table?

Comment: But what is the logic of the PrevNumber column? Where did you get that PrevNumbers (0,0,5,3)?

Comment: The first 0 in the PrevNumber determines that there was no previous record of A, PrevNumber in the next instance of A would be CurNumber of A's previous instance and so on...

Comment: Search for "*mysql workaround for missing lag() function*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ForeignKey, COALESCE(B.Number, 0) AS PrevNumber, A.Number AS CurNumber 
FROM table1 A 
LEFT JOIN table1 B ON A.ForeignKey = B.ForeignKey AND A.ID > B.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0122/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| FOREIGNKEY | PREVNUMBER | CURNUMBER |
|------------|------------|-----------|
|          A |          0 |         5 |
|          B |          0 |         3 |
|          A |          5 |         2 |
|          B |          3 |         5 |
```

**::EDIT::**

```
SELECT A.ForeignKey, COALESCE(B.Number, 0) AS PrevNumber, A.Number AS CurNumber, COALESCE(C.Number, 0) AS NextNumber
FROM table1 A 
LEFT JOIN table1 B ON A.ForeignKey = B.ForeignKey AND A.ID > B.ID
LEFT JOIN table1 C ON A.ForeignKey = C.ForeignKey AND A.ID < C.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0122/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| FOREIGNKEY | PREVNUMBER | CURNUMBER | NEXTNUMBER |
|------------|------------|-----------|------------|
|          A |          0 |         5 |          2 |
|          B |          0 |         3 |          5 |
|          A |          5 |         2 |          0 |
|          B |          3 |         5 |          0 |
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select d.FK,ISNULL(d.Prev,0) as Prev,d.Num1 as CurNumber from (
select t.Number as Num1,t.ForeignKey as FK,
(select top 1 NUmber from test where ID=t.ID-2) as Prev
   from test t
   )d
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FK  Prev    CurNumber
A   0       5
B   0       3
A   5       2
B   3       5
```